# MediaPlayer crashes on song.start()

Tags: java, android

When I run my app on the emulator, the app runs fine but when I run the app on my actual phone it crashes when I click on the button to use the play method. I used another phone to see if the app will work but it crashes again.

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    MediaPlayer song;
    boolean playing=false;
    int length;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        song = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.snakin);

    }

    public void play(View view){
        if(playing==false) {


            Button play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.play);


            song.seekTo(length);
            song.start();

            playing=true;
       }
    }
    public void pause(View view){
        Button pause=(Button)findViewById(R.id.pause);

        song.pause();
        length = song.getCurrentPosition();
        playing=false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please add your log cat.

Comment: show us your manifest. -.- remember to add the `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` also add the error that shows when it crashes

Comment: thanks for the tip guys. I've solved the problem now.

Comment: @dpeace8 add the answer. so it helps for some one.

Answer (score 0):

I've changed the mp3 file to another one. I really don't know why the first mp3 file only worked on the emulator, but my guess is that the file was corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention listeners to play and pause.
Need to mention listeners for song play and pause operations.
Here, I modified your code, you can try below given code.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    MediaPlayer song;
    boolean playing=false;
    int length;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.play);
        Button pause = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pause);
        song = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.song);



            play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(playing==false) {
                        song.seekTo(length);
                        song.start();

                        playing = true;
                    }
                }
            });
            pause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(playing==true) {
                        song.pause();
                        length = song.getCurrentPosition();
                        playing = false;
                    }
                }
            });
    }
}
```